# Android element to stay on top of app when changing activities

Tags: android

I'm trying to look for any Android Element or Window which will stay on top of the app and will not be removed when changing activities.

Android's banner seems to be per activity.
PopupWindow as well.
I can't change the app's activities - cannot change them into fragments.

Is this possible?

Comment: "I can't change the app's activities - cannot change them into fragments" -- why not?

Comment: The app needs to stay as is with multiple activities